# ¿ Por que se descolocan mis imágenes?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, imagen

Tengo una galería de imágenes que al pinchar cada una de ellas, amplia su tamaño.
El problema es que yo la tengo en un orden en `html`, pero cada vez que recargo la pagina, las imágenes cambian su orden irregularmente y desordenadamente.
Imagino que el problema vendrá de `javascript`, tengo dos archivos, uno es la versión **jQuery v2.0.2 | (c) 2005, 2013 sourceMappingURL=jquery-2.0.2.min.map** en un fichero independiente y la url que pongo creo que no funciona, pues aquí no se porque el ejemplo no funciona.
No se si podrán ayudarme con esta explicación y con estos archivos.
No se en mi archivo me pasa, pero aquí, ni funciona el aumento de pagina, ni veo que se descoloquen, ya no se como ponerlo para que puedan ayudarme.
También lo puse en [codepen](https://codepen.io/miguelitolaparra/pen/baEzPx) pero allí tampoco funciona para que puedan ver como se descolocan las imágenes.
Gracias.

```js
(function($){ 
 $.fn.least = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
   'random': true,
   'scrollToGallery': true,
   'HiDPI': false
  }, options);

  return this.each(function() {

   /* Open Images */
   function intipreview(object, path, caption) {
    /*var */
    var close = $('<figure class="close"></figure>'),
     img = $('<img src="' + path + '"/>'),
     thumb = $('li a')

    /*Cargar img  */
    img.load(
     function() {
      if ( caption.length ) {
       object.html('<article>' + caption + '</article>');
      } else {
       object.html('');
      }

      object      
       .prepend(img)
       .append(close)
       .slideDown('slow')
       thumb.removeClass('load');
     }
    );
    
    /*Cerrar pantalla completa  */  
    close.on(
     'click',
     function() {
      $('.least-preview').slideToggle('slow');
      thumb.removeClass('active');
     }
    );
   }

   /*Miniatura  */
   $(this).find('li a').click(
    function(e) {

     /*var  */
     var $$ = $(this),
      path = $$.attr('href'),
      preview = $('.least-preview'),
      previewImg = preview.children('img'),
      caption = $$.attr('data-caption') || '';

     /*Misma imagen  */
     if ( previewImg.length && path === previewImg.attr('src') ) {
      preview.slideToggle('slow');

      $$.toggleClass('active');
       
      return;
     }

     /*Otra imagen */
     if ( previewImg.length ) {

      $$.addClass('active');
      $('.least-gallery li a.active').removeClass('active');

      preview.slideUp(
       'slow',
       function() {
        intipreview(
         preview,
         path,
         caption
        );
       }
      );

     /*Primera imagen */
     } else {
      intipreview(
       preview,
       path,
       caption
      );
     }

     /*Añadir barra de carga */
     $$.addClass('load active');
    }
   );
   
   /* */
   if(settings.random) {
    $('.least-gallery').each(function(){
     var ul = $(this),
      li = ul.children('li');
      
      li.sort(function() {
       var temp = parseInt( Math.random()*8, null ),
        OddEven = temp%4,
        PosNeg = temp>2 ? 1 : -1;
        
        return ( OddEven*PosNeg );
      })
      .appendTo(ul);
    });
   }

   /* Vuelve al comienzo */
   if(settings.scrollToGallery) {
    $(this).find('li a').click(
     function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $('html, body').animate(
       { 
        scrollTop: $('#least').offset().top
       }, 500 
      );
     }
    );
   }

   /* Support Retina Image - Inspiration https://bensmann.no */
   if(settings.HiDPI) {
    if(window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
     /* var's */
     var image_thumb = $('#least img'),
      image_big = $('#least a');

      /* Substitua imagens com @ 2x */
     for(var i = 0; i < image_thumb.length && image_big.length; i++) {
      var src = image_thumb[i].src,
       href = image_big[i].href,
       j = src.lastIndexOf('.'),
       k = href.lastIndexOf('.');

       src = src.substr(0,j) + '@2x' + src.substr(j);
       href = href.substr(0,k) + '@2x' + href.substr(k);

       image_thumb[i].src = src;
       image_big[i].href = href;
     }
    }
   }
  });
 };
})(jQuery);

//# sourceMappingURL=./least.min.map
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
* {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  border: 0;
}
#least {
  min-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}
#least .least-preview {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: #f1f0f0;
  padding: 50px 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  display: none;
}
#least .least-preview img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
#least .least-preview .close {
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url("../img/close.svg");
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
#least .least-preview article {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#least .least-preview article strong {
  font-weight: 800;
}
#least .least-gallery {
  font-size: 0;
}
#least .least-gallery li {
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;

}
#least .least-gallery li a {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
  -webkit-transition-property: outline-color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition-property: outline-color;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition-property: outline-color;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -o-transition-property: outline-color;
  -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  transition-property: outline-color;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  outline-color: white;
}
#least .least-gallery li a img {
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
}
#least .least-gallery li a.active {
  outline: 2px solid;
  outline-color: #666666;
}
#least .least-gallery li a.load:after {
  content: url("../img/loading.svg");
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -20px 0 0 0;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666666;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 800;
}
#least .least-gallery li a:hover {
  outline: 2px solid;
  outline-color: #666666;
}
#least .least-gallery li a:hover:before {
  content: attr(data-subtitle);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666666;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 175px;
  font-weight: 200;
  width: 240px;
  height: 150px;
  background: black;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#least .least-gallery li a:hover:after {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -30px 0 0 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid;
  border-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #666666;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>
galeria
        </title>

        <meta name="description" content="least.js 2 - Random and Responsive HiDPI jQuery Gallery based on HTML5 and CSS3">
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        
        <!-- Responsive viewport for smartphone devices -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <!-- least.js 2 CSS file -->
        <link href="src/css/least.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>

   <br>

        <!-- Least Gallery -->
        <section id="least">
                <h1>Mi galeria</h1>
                <br>
                <br>
                
            <!-- Least Gallery: Fullscreen Preview -->
            <div class="least-preview"></div>
            
            <!-- Least Gallery: Thumbnails -->
            <ul class="least-gallery">
                <!-- 1 || Element with data-caption ||-->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://i66.tinypic.com/f22e51.jpg" title="" data-subtitle="" >
                        <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/f22e51.jpg" alt="Alt Image Text" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <!-- 2 || Element with data-caption as href-attribute ||-->-->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://i65.tinypic.com/1044421.jpg" title="" data-subtitle="" >
                        <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1044421.jpg" alt="Alt Image Text" />
                    </a>
                </li>
                
                <!-- 3 -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://i65.tinypic.com/1044421.jpg" title="" data-subtitle="Antes de empezar.">
                        <img src="http://i65.tinypic.com/1044421.jpg" alt="Alt Image Text" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <!-- 4 -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://i66.tinypic.com/2h7faxc.jpg" title="Terminado..." data-subtitle="." >
                        <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2h7faxc.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <!-- 5 -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://i67.tinypic.com/344wbuw.jpg" title="Antes de..." data-subtitle="comenzar." >
                        <img src="http://i67.tinypic.com/344wbuw.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>

                <!-- 6 -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://i66.tinypic.com/2i794zo.jpg" title="Concluido..." data-subtitle="" >
                        <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2i794zo.jpg" alt="" />
                    </a>
                </li>

               
            </ul>

        </section>
        <!-- Least Gallery end -->

        <!-- jQuery library -->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="src/js/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- least.js library -->
        <script src="src/js/libs/least/least.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.least-gallery').least();
            });
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Ya encontraste la solución?

Comment: No gracias, la verdad es que ni me acordaba de esto

Comment: Estoy buscando algo, ya que me pasa igual, si lo encuentro lo publico ;)

Comment: He mirado por si en servidor funcionaba, pero sí que se descolocan al cargar la página.  publica tu otra pregunta con mas detalles que la mía, y mejor explicada. O quizá si pones una recompensa en la mía llame la atención, pero yo la publicaré con más detalles y mejor que la mía, y de poner recompensa lo haces en la tuya, que ya ves no tuvo éxito. Suerte @ChristopherVilla